# Do changes made with SharedPreferences.Editor survive a device reboot?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

If an application stores something using `SharedPreferences.Editor`'s methods, does it survive a device reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `commit()` or `apply()` the changes that you make in the `SharedPreferences.Editor`, then yes. `SharedPreferences` are saved in an XML file, and that file will survive an ordinary reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. Though shared preference data are temporary and not a recommendation for saving long term or complex data but it values can only be cleared using Editor.clear ones commit() or apply()

Comment: Just to note, Shared Preference data is not temporary, values are written to disk in an xml file inside the app storage.  As long as your code doesn't clear them out, they will live there as long as the app is installed.